# Using 2 worksheets to calculate in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, mode

I have data that goes back to 2004 to deal with so have to simplify calculations moving from using Excel to using SQL to save processing time & pressure on our servers.

My data is:

```
Period  Employee    EmOrg       EmType  Total Hours     Mode 
201306  GOVINP1     RSA/PZB/T00 S       180             66 
201306  LANDCJ1     RSA/PZB/T00 S       200             35 
201306  WOODRE      RSA/PZB/T00 S       180             34 
201306  MOKOHM1     RSA/JNB/T00 S       160             33 
201306  KAPPPJ      RSA/PLZ/T00 S       160             32 
201306  CAHISJ      RSA/PZB/T00 S       187             31 
201306  ZEMUN       RSA/PZB/T00 S       180             31 
201306  SAULDD1     RSA/PZB/T00 S       190             28 
201306  JEROP1      RSA/DUR/T00 S       188             26 
201306  NGOBS1      RSA/PZB/T00 S       204             24 
201306  ZONDNS2     RSA/PZB/T00 S       192             23 
201306  DLAMMP      RSA/PZB/T00 S       201             23 
201306  MPHURK      RSA/PLZ/T00 S       160             22 
201306  MNDAMB      RSA/PZB/T00 S       188             21
```

My desired outcome is:

```
Period  EmOrg       EmType  TotalHours  FTE S
201308  RSA/BFN/T00 S       198         1
201308  RSA/CPT/T00 S       744         3.757575
201308  RSA/DUR/T00 S       805         4.065656
201308  RSA/JNB/T00 S       396         2
201308  RSA/PLZ/T00 S       563         2.843434
201308  RSA/PTA/T00 S       594         3
201308  RSA/PZB/T00 S       4882        24.656565
```

And my query:

```
SELECT 
    LD.Period,
    LD.EmOrg,
    LD.EmType,
    Sum(LD.RegHrs) AS 'Total Hours',
    Sum(LD.RegHrs) / 198 As 'FTE_S'
FROM
    SSI.dbo.LD LD
GROUP BY LD.Period , LD.EmOrg , LD.EmType
HAVING (LD.EmOrg Like '%T00')
    AND (LD.EmType = 'S')
```

How do I refer to a column in a different worksheet to use as my Mode rather than dividing with an actual number? Because different months have a different mode and using an actual number will give wrong output in other months.

Comment: please give some raw table data. what is your schema?

Comment: Period Employee EmOrg EmType Total Hours Mode
201306 GOVINP1 RSA/PZB/T00 S 180 66
201306 LANDCJ1 RSA/PZB/T00 S 200 35
201306 WOODRE RSA/PZB/T00 S 180 34
201306 MOKOHM1 RSA/JNB/T00 S 160 33
201306 KAPPPJ RSA/PLZ/T00 S 160 32
201306 CAHISJ RSA/PZB/T00 S 187 31
201306 ZEMUN RSA/PZB/T00 S 180 31
201306 SAULDD1 RSA/PZB/T00 S 190 28
201306 JEROP1 RSA/DUR/T00 S 188 26
201306 NGOBS1 RSA/PZB/T00 S 204 24
201306 ZONDNS2 RSA/PZB/T00 S 192 23
201306 DLAMMP RSA/PZB/T00 S 201 23
201306 MPHURK RSA/PLZ/T00 S 160 22
201306 MNDAMB RSA/PZB/T00 S 188 21

**example of data I use in my first spreadsheet**

Comment: ill add to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate table for your Mode per month and than use JOIN to get that value and use it.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    LD.Period,
    LD.EmOrg,
    LD.EmType,
    Sum(LD.RegHrs) AS 'Total Hours',
    Sum(LD.RegHrs) / M.Mode As 'FTE_S'
FROM
    SSI.dbo.LD LD
INNER JOIN SSI.dbo.Mode M
    ON LD.Period = M.Period -- Not sure its should be Period or Month
GROUP BY LD.Period , LD.EmOrg , LD.EmType
HAVING (LD.EmOrg Like '%T00')
    AND (LD.EmType = 'S')
```